# https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send not getting response in postman

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

For checking data payload notification in background i m checking in postman using

> https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

I put all necessary key values like *Authorization* and  *Content-Type*.

While i hit the send button in postman i m not able to get response.

> Could not get any response There was an error connecting to
>
> https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send. Why this might have happened: The
> server couldn't send a response: Ensure that the backend is working
> properly Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked: Fix this by
> turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General Proxy
> configured incorrectly Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in
> Settings > Proxy Request timeout: Change request timeout in Settings >
> General

I did all as above mentioned.

Advanced help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have same problem. Not sure, what's wrong with postman, but via curl it works OK.

Comment: Its because of token will not be saved properly to your back end.

Comment: And did you solved it somehow?